# How does the browser understand with what namespace we works?

Tags: html, namespaces

Example:

```css
@namespace html "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
@namespace svg "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

html|a{ 
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
svg|a {
    stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
<svg>
  <a href="#">
    <text y="21" x="60">link</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

As you can see there are 2 links, but the rule for each link is different, because the browser understands to what space I'm referring. So how does the browser understand what namespace I'm working with? Because if you write `@namespace my "http://example.com"` it does not apply to anything because the browser does not understand such namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, the HTML5 parser looks at the element that would be the parent of the next element to be added to the DOM as it processes each token. Ordinarily, it puts each element in the same namespace as its parent element. It starts off expecting elements to be in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace, but when it processes the `<svg>` start tag, it knows that the `<svg>` element is in the `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` namespace. So elements that are contained by the svg element are also put in the `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` namespace. When it processes the `</svg>` end tag, the parent element of the next tag won't be the svg element, so it will to expect elements in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace again.

Other tags can also cause a switch back to the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace, but the `<a>` and `</a>` tags are not among them. See [A start tag whose tag name is "svg"](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-in-body-insertion-mode), [the tree construction dispatcher](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#tree-construction-dispatcher) and  [The rules for parsing tokens in foreign content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inforeign) for details.

Comment: Your message is clear to me. However, the links that you provided on the specification put me in to a grinding halt.. I just do not understand some excerpts, I need your help.

The first that means: `If the adjusted current node is an element in the SVG namespace`. About which *element in namespace SVG* there is a speech?

Tree dispatcher: There are just some conditions without steps of action, how is this to be understood? For example, when there is a tokenization there each condition is described by an action, I think you understand me.

Comment: With the tree dispatcher it's just a case of if any of the first eight cases hold, use the current insertion mode, otherwise use the foreign content rules. I'm not sure what your first question is asking. The "adjusted current node" is the bottom entry in the stack of open elements. Typically that's the node which will become the parent of the next inserted element in the DOM document, although it's possible that through scripting, the current node has already been removed from the DOM document.

Comment: At this link https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-rules-for-parsing-tokens-in-foreign-content I have most of all misunderstandings. I correctly understand that under `foreign content` is meant the contents of the elements Math and SVG? If this is so then under paragraph: `A start tag whose tag name is "font", if the token has any attributes named "color", "face", or "size"` I'm not sure how the one-time can be:`a parsing error`, `act as described in the "any other start tag"` and `pop an element from the stack of open elements`?

Comment: I also asked you about an element in the SVG namespace. It was about `Any other start tag`. So I do not understand what element in the SVG nasmespace it is? Is this <svg> itself or any element from the svg namespace?

Comment: I'll take your second question first. There are places in svg where child elements and their descendants are not expected to be svg. i,e. They could validly be html elements. For example, inside a `<foreignObject>` element. So if there was a p element, inside a foreignObject element inside an svg element, the svg element and the foreignObject element will be elements in the svg namespace and the p element will be an element in the html namespace.

Comment: But that's not what the behaviour described under `A start tag whose tag name is "font", if the token has any attributes named "color", "face", or "size"` is about. That is about the parser encountering html markup inside svg in an unexpected place - i.e. garbage markup. As is normal with html parsing, the parser tries to handle the garbage as best it can, essentially by closing open elements until it reaches an ancestor that would normally contain html elements.

Comment: Actually, maybe I misunderstood your second question. At the point in the rules for parsing foreign content where it reaches the `Any other start tag...` case, there are only two possibilities for the adjusted current node. It *must* be (because of what has been parsed up that point) either an element in the mathML namespace or an element in the svg namespace.

Comment: I invited you in chat to discus. Can you join?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177673/discussion-between-maximpro-and-alohci).

Comment: An example needs to be made clear. Quote: **"If the adjusted current node is an element in the SVG namespace ..."** - what can be in this case the *adjusted current node*? Is this the `<svg>` element itself or are the elements of the svg namespace?

Comment: As for `foreignObject`, I understand it like this: `<svg><foreignObject><p>some content</p></foreignObject></svg>` The `foreignObject` element acts as a container that will allow writing tags from other namespaces. If you write outside `foreignObject`, then `<p>` will simply pop out of the `<svg>` node - I tested it, so I say this. However, I did not understand what you mentioned `foreignObject`.

Comment: In one of my questions, you said that it could happen - a *garbage markup* inside svg, could not give examples related to this item:  `A start tag whose tag name is "font", if the token has any attributes named "color", "face", or "size"` that is, consider all cases (3), because I have problems with this.

Comment: It would be nice if you joined the chat, because here it is not very convenient to write because of the limitations of characters on the comment

Comment: To be honest, I'm struggling to understand your questions. What is it about "an element in the svg namespace" that you don't understand? It is what it is. But it seems that the discussion is drifting away from the original question. Maybe you would fair better if you asked a whole new question or questions focused on the specific points you don't understand.

Comment: Yes, it's probably better to create a new question, but who will answer? Even if only you responded to this question. I could describe my questions it in more detail, but you do not join the chat

Comment: Can you look my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778481/some-questions-about-tree-construction-html-spec

Comment: I looked, but it's really far too broad to be answered. Sorry.

Comment: And what do I need to do? Break into three separate issues?

Comment: I asked another more important for me question, can you look him https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807178/understanding-rules-for-parsing-tokens-in-foreign-content